# Android studio cant resolve symbol R

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, import

I am having a very strange problem with android studio - every time I attempt to run the application I get the error cant resolve symbol R. I have googled the problem and have tried cleaning and rebuilding my project. I'm pretty sure my XML files are right too. But I am new to Android development so I could be wrong. [Here is an image of the error when I try rebuild the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CUwt.png)
Here is the [whole project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoY21SRGhrZ1p2Qm8/view?usp=sharing) if you would like to take a look.

I am finding it hard to narrow down the problem. Really appreciate any help thanks

Comment: There are tons and tons of Stackoverflow questions about this already. I suggest you start by reading through the many answers on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

import android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt.activity.R;

Comment: I got the solution .. Remove this line import.android.loginfirstattempt.activity.R;   and just import learning1.gaz.com.learning_1.R;  to all of your activity. It works on my side

Comment: ah yes this worked, thanks a lot! Would you be able to explain why it has to be like this? thanks

Comment: R.java file is inbuilt as you know and you tried to import it from your package instead of its actual path where it resides :)

Comment: Ah makes sense, I really appreciate the help thank you